# Appending a list item during reccursion call(at the end I get empty list)

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have a list of lists( in total 10 elements) and I am trying to calculate the number of strongly connected components in the graph(but don't worry about it).

Here is how my list look like:

```
df_reversed_back =[[9, 7],
 [8, 9],
 [7, 8],
 [6, 9],
 [6, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [4, 5],
 [3, 5],
 [3, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [1, 2]]
```

where the first element of the inner list - is vertex number one[9], and second element is a second vertex[7].

My problem is , that in recursion calls I append a list to the list, that exists outside the function.

```
all_components = []
SSC = []
explored= []
#c)modification of DFS
def DFS_2_Path(graph,node):
    #global SSC
    global all_components
    explored.append(node)
    print('Node:',node)
    #index = [ind for ind,vertex  in enumerate(df_reverse) if vertex[0] == node]
    for second_vert in graph:
        print('Second_vert:',second_vert)
        print('Second_vert[0] == node:',second_vert[0] == node)
        if second_vert[0] == node:
            print('second_vert[1] not in explored :',second_vert[1] not in explored)
            if second_vert[1] not in explored:
                print('SSC was:',SSC)
                SSC.append(second_vert[1])
                print('SSC is:',SSC)
                print('---------------------------------')
                print('NEXT ITERATION OF THE INNER LOOP')
                print('-------------------------------------')
                DFS_2_Path(graph,second_vert[1])
            if second_vert[1] in explored and len(SSC)> 0 :#check if second vert is not explored and if it's not a new SSC
                print('SSC was:',SSC)
                SSC.append(second_vert[1])
                print('SSC is:',SSC)

                all_components.append(SSC)
                print('All_components is :',all_components)
                SSC[:] = []

    print('All_components was:',all_components)


for i in range(max(df_reversed_back[0]),0,-1):
    if i not in explored:
        s = i
        DFS_2_Path(df_reversed_back,i)
```

As you see, i want to append SSC to the all_components.
The Result must be: all_components = [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]

But at the end I get: all_components =[[], [], []]

Can you tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: I don't see why this should be done recursively in the first place

Comment: Because *you clear the contents of `SCC`* right here: `SSC[:] = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying the contents of `SSC` when you do this:

```
all_components.append(SSC)
print('All_components is :',all_components)
SSC[:] = []
```

This effectively adds a reference to `SSC` to `all_components` and then erases the contents of the array the global variable is pointing to.

Perhaps a better way is to create a new SSC when needed by including it as a parameter to the function.

You can make your function read:

```
def DFS_2_Path(graph,node, SSC=None):
    if SSC == None:
        SSC = []
```

Then when you call it recursively, pass it into the recursion with:

```
DFS_2_Path(graph,second_vert[1], SSC)
```

This will allow each recursive path to get it's own `SSC` array and as a bonus, you won't need the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
            all_components.append(SSC)
            print('All_components is :',all_components)
            SSC[:] = []
```

You make `SSC` an element of `all_components`, but immediately empty it.  This leaves `all_components` as a list containing an empty list.  Then you continue using the master list (SSC) for manipulations.  You can see this in your output:

```
SSC was: [1, 2]
SSC is: [1, 2, 3]
All_components is : [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
Second_vert: [1, 2]
Second_vert[0] == node: False
All_components was: [[], [], []]
All_components was: [[], [], []]
```

Each element is merely a reference to the original `SSC`: you see it as triplets being either empty or the final component.

I suspect that you wanted a snapshot (copy) of `SSC` to get appended:

```
            all_components.append(SSC[:])
            print('All_components is :',all_components)
            SSC[:] = []
```

Output:

```
...
All_components was: [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```